# Update table entry by taking sum from another table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I use the following query to see the sum of price times quantity for all the products in a package.

```
select 
    a.nid, a.packagename,
    case
       when sum(b.quantity * c.price) is null 
          then 0 
          else sum(b.quantity * c.price) 
    end 
from 
    tblpackage as a
left join
    tblpackage_service as b on a.nid = b.package_id
left join 
    tblproduct as c on c.nid = b.service_id
group by 
    a.nid, a.packagename
```

which returns the following result

```
nid  packagename      (No Column Name)
---------------------------------------
6    Test Package 4    400.00
3    Test Package 5     0.00
5    Test Package 6   1350.00
8    Test Package 7    350.00
7    Test Package 8    400.00
9    Test Package 9    400.00
1    Test Package 1      0.00
2    Test Package 2      0.00
4    Test Package 3   3900.00
```

Now I update the same using

```
update tblpackage 
set tblpackage.amount = case 
                           when sum(b.quantity * c.price) is null 
                              then 0 
                              else sum(b.quantity * c.price) 
                        end 
from tblpackage AS a
left join tblpackage_service as b on a.nid = b.package_id
left join tblproduct as c on c.nid = b.service_id
```

and I get an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

So is there any way to do this using the update query.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would work better.

```
 ;WITH newtblpackage_service AS(
        SELECT package_id,SUM(quantity*price) as sum1 
        FROM tblpackage_service a left join tblproduct as c on c.nid = a.service_id
        GROUP BY package_id
) 

update tblpackage 
set tblpackage.amount = CASE WHEN sum1 IS NULL 
                             THEN 0 
                             ELSE sum1
                        END 
from tblpackage AS a
left join newtblpackage_service as b on a.nid = b.package_id
```

Because tblpackage_service can be used to find the sum(so it seems).

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
;WITH tblpackage_serviceCTE AS(
        SELECT package_id,SUM(quantity ) as quantity 
        FROM tblpackage_service
        GROUP BY package_id
),tblproductCTE AS(
        SELECT nid,SUM(price) as price
        FROM tblproduct
        GROUP BY nid
)  
update tblpackage 
set tblpackage.amount = CASE WHEN tblpackage_serviceCTE.quantity * tblproductCTE .price) IS NULL 
                             THEN 0 
                             ELSE tblpackage_serviceCTE.quantity * tblproductCTE .price 
                        END 
from tblpackage AS a
left join tblpackage_serviceCTE as b on a.nid = b.package_id
left join tblproductCTE as c on c.nid = b.service_id
```

Note : Take backup first :p

Comment: dosen't work as price is not part of tblpackage_service

Comment: @rexroxm `tblpackage_service` was typo `tblproduct` should be there in second ctc :0

Comment: sure but by creating the tblproductCTE I won't be able to join it with tblpackageCTE as there is no service_id in it.